# One group before and one group after the first match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and I'm finding it very confusing. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to separate this string in two groups

```
Lorem ipsum\/|/ | dolor sit654 | amet consectetur
```

Group 1: `Lorem ipsum\/|/`

Group 2: `dolor sit654 | amet consectetur`

The pattern is the `|` ("space" + "vertical bar" + "space")

I want to get everything before and after the first match of these characters above each in a group

I've tried writing a regex like this, with no sucess:
`/(.*?)(\s\|\s)(.*)/`

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems that the regex is ok. Why do you say it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp works fine:

```
let str = 'Lorem ipsum\/|/ | dolor sit654 | amet consectetur';
console.log(str.match(/(.*?)(\s\|\s)(.*)/))
```

Output:

```
Array(4) [ "Lorem ipsum/|/ | dolor sit654 | amet consectetur", "Lorem ipsum/|/", " | ", "dolor sit654 | amet consectetur" ]
```

You could improve it by removing the 2nd capturing group

```
console.log(str.match(/(.*?)\s\|\s(.*)/))
```

Output:

```
Array(3) [ "Lorem ipsum/|/ | dolor sit654 | amet consectetur", "Lorem ipsum/|/", "dolor sit654 | amet consectetur" ]
```

or making it non-capturing:

```
console.log(str.match(/(.*?)(?:\s\|\s)(.*)/))
```

Output:

```
Array(3) [ "Lorem ipsum/|/ | dolor sit654 | amet consectetur", "Lorem ipsum/|/", "dolor sit654 | amet consectetur" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently *capturing* the initial `|` in a group - but you want group 2 to be the second substring, not the separating characters. Either move those outside of a group:

```
(.*?) \| (.*)
     ^^^^
```

Or use a non-capturing group instead:

```
(.*?)(?: \| )(.*)
     ^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/v7ZRr1/1

```js
console.log(
  `Lorem ipsum\/|/ | dolor sit654 | amet consectetur`
  .match(/(.*?) \| (.*)/)
);
```

Comment: Looks like we were both typing at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` with your regex minus the middle capture group. `split` used this way will leave extraneous empty strings on the ends of the array, but you can `filter()` these easily with:

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum\/|/ | dolor sit654 | amet consectetur'

let arr = str.split(/(.*?)\s\|\s(.*)/).filter(s => s)
console.log(arr)
```